# Python Launcher crashing when trying to use matplotlib

Tags: python, video-tracking

I am trying to run the code from https://github.com/abewley/sort
It works when running it without the argument display, however, while running

```
python sort.py --display
```

the python launcher(to display the result) crashes but the rest of the code runs fine.

the relevant part of the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # all train
  sequences = ['PETS09-S2L1','TUD-Campus','TUD-Stadtmitte','ETH-Bahnhof','ETH-Sunnyday','ETH-Pedcross2','KITTI-13','KITTI-17','ADL-Rundle-6','ADL-Rundle-8','Venice-2']
  args = parse_args()
  display = args.display
  phase = 'train'
  total_time = 0.0
  total_frames = 0
  colours = np.random.rand(32,3) #used only for display
  if(display):
    if not os.path.exists('mot_benchmark'):
      print('\n\tERROR: mot_benchmark link not found!\n\n    Create a symbolic link to the MOT benchmark\n    (https://motchallenge.net/data/2D_MOT_2015/#download). E.g.:\n\n    $ ln -s /path/to/MOT2015_challenge/2DMOT2015 mot_benchmark\n\n')
      exit()
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure() 

  if not os.path.exists('output'):
    os.makedirs('output')

  for seq in sequences:
    mot_tracker = Sort() #create instance of the SORT tracker
    seq_dets = np.loadtxt('data/%s/det.txt'%(seq),delimiter=',') #load detections
    with open('output/%s.txt'%(seq),'w') as out_file:
      print("Processing %s."%(seq))
      for frame in range(int(seq_dets[:,0].max())):
        frame += 1 #detection and frame numbers begin at 1
        dets = seq_dets[seq_dets[:,0]==frame,2:7]
        dets[:,2:4] += dets[:,0:2] #convert to [x1,y1,w,h] to [x1,y1,x2,y2]
        total_frames += 1

        if(display):
          ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
          fn = 'mot_benchmark/%s/%s/img1/%06d.jpg'%(phase,seq,frame)
          im =io.imread(fn)
          ax1.imshow(im)
          plt.title(seq+' Tracked Targets')


        start_time = time.time()
        trackers = mot_tracker.update(dets)
        cycle_time = time.time() - start_time
        total_time += cycle_time

        for d in trackers:
          print('%d,%d,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,1,-1,-1,-1'%(frame,d[4],d[0],d[1],d[2]-d[0],d[3]-d[1]),file=out_file)
          if(display):
            d = d.astype(np.int32)
            ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((d[0],d[1]),d[2]-d[0],d[3]-d[1],fill=False,lw=3,ec=colours[d[4]%32,:]))
            ax1.set_adjustable('box')

        if(display):
          fig.canvas.flush_events()
          plt.draw()
          ax1.cla()

  print("Total Tracking took: %.3f for %d frames or %.1f FPS"%(total_time,total_frames,total_frames/total_time))
  if(display):
    print("Note: to get real runtime results run without the option: --display")
```